# Can't get Ajax call back data on the back-end plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have wp plugin that when it reutrns the ajax data of **woocommerce** billing fields  in the php function it printed in the console browser, in the `index.php` file of the plugin
So I want to be able to get the data normally but for some reason I can't however I have another ajax call on the same localhost runs normally.
function addEvtListenerToCheckoutPage2()
{

```
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

            document.getElementById('billing_first_name').addEventListener("focusout", function() {
                alert("Hello World!addEvtListenerToCheckoutPage2");
                if (document.getElementById('billing_first_name') !== "") {

                    var billing_first_name = document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value;

                    
                    my_data = {
                         
                        action: 'shipping',
                        billing_first_name_post: document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value
                    };
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "get",

                        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                        data: my_data,
                        success: function(msg) {
                            console.log("sucess ajax");
                            console.log(msg);
                        },
                        fail: function(msg) {

                            console.log("error ajax");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
<?php


}
// can't use any action instead of init but it's fine for now
add_action('init', 'addEvtListenerToCheckoutPage2');
```

in the rest of the same file

```
   function shipping1()
    {
        $testing =  $_GET['billing_first_name_post'];
        echo $testing; 
        wp_send_json_success();
// this printed in the console not on the server or I mean doesn't process on the back-end
// this's the result which again in the consle : Steve{"success":true}
    
       test_function(); // this's another php function which also when I run it prints in the console
       
 
    
    
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_shipping', 'shipping1');
    add_action('shipping', 'shipping1');
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your description, what the actual problem is supposed to be. `echo $testing; wp_send_json_success();` - echoing a "plain" value will invalidate any JSON you might send after it, perhaps that is the reason for your (unclear) problem already.

Comment: when I use `wp_send_json_success();`  the function stops at this point and also prints `true` in the console

Comment: The idea everthing and anythig in the call back function of php which is `shipping1` runs in the console not on the back-end

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say with that last comment.